# WiFi to Bluetooth Streaming

Tags: wifi, networking, audio, bluetooth, music

I'm looking for a solution for the following scenario.
I don't know whether or not there's such a device available, but for the sake of convenience, I'll call the requested solution a "device".

I have a (TP-Link Archer V600 v3) router, supportive of external USB storage.
That storage device holds MP3 files. I'd like to be able to listen to them through regular Bluetooth speakers or headphones.

I'm looking for a "device" which could, typically, browse through the MP3 files on the network storage, and play a selected file(s) to any Bluetooth device (connected to it).

Few important notes:

- The device must **not** have internet access (but rather only to the network storage).
- Device must be operable over AC power **continuously**.
- Device optional support for operation over (built-in) rechargeable batteries is a big plus.
- A device having no functionality other than audio playing/streaming - a huge advantage.
- If device supports playing to multiple Bluetooth outputs concurrently - the better.
- The *router* is capable of mapping the storage device connected to it, or even a specific path within in, to a network-path or to a local FTP URL, etc. It seems that storage could also be accessed through a 'Media Server' interface [I don't know what it means in the context of this router], although it seems it does not support specific-folder sharing (which is preferred). Please see all USB-sharing options in the following screenshot: [image: TP-Link Router USB-Sharing Options Screenshot]

**Your advice would be much obliged.**